# Extract files contained in archive.tar.gz to new directory named archive

Tags: tar

I have a directory containing about 800 .tgz archives, each containing about 10 files. Effectively, I want to convert each archive into a directory of the same name. Is there a simple one line command to do this, or should I write a script?

Comment: You can specify that in the command itself `tar -xvzf filename.tar.gz -C /desired/path`

Comment: -C will not work if dir does not exists. Better run: `mkdir -p dirpath && tar xzf archive.tar.gz -C dirpath`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Update since GNU tar 1.28:
use `--one-top-level`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#index-one_002dtop_002dlevel_002c-summary

Older versions need to script this. You can specify the directory that the extract is placed in by using the tar -C option.

The script below assumes that the directories do not exist and must be created. If the directories do exist the script will still work - the mkdir will simply fail.

```
tar -xvzf archive.tar.gx -C archive_dir
```

e.g.

```
for a in *.tar.gz
do
    a_dir=${a%.tar.gz}
    mkdir --parents $a_dir
    tar -xvzf $a -C $a_dir
done
```

Comment: Yes, I thought I would probably need a script - thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: The script worked well but I needed to add "mkdir $a_dir".

Answer (score 20):

If modern enough `GNU tar` is being taken into account then this should be top answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478341/34069

For brevity this is extract:

```
tar -xvf bash.html_node.tar.gz --one-top-level
```

It extracts archive into new directory named after archive file name.

Comment: No it shouldn't, `--one-top-level does` not exist in the GNU version of tar. Meaning it's not supported on OSX and some versions of Linux.

Comment: @IanSmith - ok, good point - but you mean probably "it does  not exist in BSD version ..."

Comment: Yep :), it definitely should be included.

Comment: The option --one-top-level was added to GNU tar in version 1.28, released 2014-07-28, see release notes here: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/

Answer (score 4):

Create a folder in which you want to extract like this `mkdir archive`
and pass folder name with -C while extracting,
 `tar -xvf archive.zip -C archive`

Answer (score 0):

To extract files from one directory to second directory while keeping the filename in the second directory i.e without the complete file path and file extension

```
%sh
for file in /mnt/dir1/*.tar.gz; 
do 
y=${file##*/}; 
z=${y%%.*}; 
mkdir -p /mnt/dir2/$z && tar -xzvf $file -C /mnt/dir2/$z;
done
```

Answer (score -4):

Well, if you run `$ tar -zxf some-archive.tar.gz -C .`, (note the dot at the end) a new directory called `some-archive/` will be created in the directory you are currently in.

Maybe this is what you meant by your question? This is what I generally want so it may work for you as well.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer the question. `-C .` is redundant because the default output directly is the current directory anyway.