# How to extract tgz file "with" a folder

Tags: bash, sh, tar

In OS X, double click `X.tgz` will generate a folder named`X`, putting all files into the folder (the folder name follows the `.tgz` file's name).

I want to do the same thing in the terminal.

However, `tar -xvzf /pathtofile/X.tgz` will extract all files and put them in `/pathtofile/`.

And by `tar -xvzf /pathtofile/X.tgz -C /newpath/`  the newpath does not automatically follows the .tgz file name(i.e. in this case a folder named "X").

Does anyone know if there is a simple way to do this?

Comment: SO Is not the place for this kind of questions, try SuperUser, Unix & Linux Stack Exchange or maybe even man tar

Comment: SO users may not welcome this kind of comments. Good programmers do not have the "superiority complex". Post related and helpful answers/comments or you shall try another website.

Comment: Actually, the site is full of this kind of comments. The point is not to make you feel bad about your question, but to direct you to the right place. Your question is off topic and is vaguely related (if any) to programming. Again, that's why other Stack communities exist and you'll be better of asking there.

Comment: Well, thanks for your suggestion anyway. I would say a clumsy but possible solution could be bash code which replaces the location folder name with the file name. And the point is I won't feel bad about posting this question because the question exists and I didn't find a solution. And also I could and I do think people could feel a certain allusively disparaging something with regard to your first comment.

Comment: I've answered your question based off of your most recent comment. This has been asked before and the answer gives you a great head start on what needs to be done (Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007947/extract-files-contained-in-archive-tar-gz-to-new-directory-named-archive)

Answer (score 0):

Use the strip-component flag in tar:

```
tar --strip-components=1
```

Comment: First, thanks for the help. the flag "Remove the specified number of leading path elements. ", it seems that it does not add elements to the path. I tried both `tar *.tgz --strip-components=-1` and `tar *.tgz --strip-components=1`, but still get the same result as described.

Answer (score 0):

This bash function does what you asked to do, which is basically just creating the directory using the filename without the ".tgz"

```
extract_to_dir () {
    filename=$1
    dirname="${filename%.*}"
    mkdir ./$dirname
    tar -xvzf $filename -C $dirname
}
```

Usage would be:

```
extract_to_dir filename.tgz
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question thoroughly. I'll post an answer later.

Comment: @K.J No answer was ever posted huh?

Comment: make a temp folder -> do the operation inside -> move to the destination folder and delete the temp